# Unit testing error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm trying to implement some unit tests in my rails3 application. The following is my '`test_helper.rb`' file.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  fixtures :all
end
```

Following my fixture file (`site_layouts.yml`)

```
# Read about fixtures at http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html

one:
  name: layout1
  content: <html><head></head><body>layout1</body></html>

two:
  name: layout2
  content: <html><head></head><body>layout2</body></html>
```

and following is my Unit test class

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  fixtures :site_layouts
  test "show site layout" do
    layout = site_layouts(:one)   
  end
end
```

and when I try to run the `rake test:units` I'm getting the following error

```
undefined method `fixtures' for SiteLayoutTest:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I'm a little new to testing. I'm on

- Rails 3.0.0
- Linux
- test-unit (2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.2, 1.2.3)
- test-unit-notify (0.3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the `fixtures :site_layouts` call inside `SiteLayoutTest`. Rails should auto load your fixtures.

More about fixtures in the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

Answer (score 1):

Should you derive from the ActiveSupport::TestCase you've created in test_helper.rb? That should autoload your fixtures

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "show site layout" do
    layout = site_layouts(:one)   
  end
end
```